# Testing/mocking 3rd party packages in Golang

Tags: testing, go, tdd

I'm new to Golang and have been taking a TDD approach while learning the language. I've been getting along okay yet I find testing third party packages quite clunky, which leads me to believe that I've been taking the wrong approach.

The specific case I'm having trouble with is mocking a [Redis client](https://github.com/go-redis/redis) for error handling. The approach I've taken is to create my own interface, and the implementation wraps the clients methods that I want to use.

```
type Redis interface {
    Get(key string) (string, error)
}

type RedisClient struct {
    client *redis.Client
}

func (redisClient *RedisClient) New(client *redis.Client) *RedisClient {
    redisClient.client = client

    return redisClient
}

func (redisClient *RedisClient) Get(key string) (string, error) {
    return redisClient.client.Get(key).Result()
}
```

I can then create a mock which implements that same interface to return whichever values I specify, particularly for testing error handling.

I've hit a roadblock where a specific method on the client to [perform transactions](https://godoc.org/github.com/go-redis/redis#Client.TxPipeline) (MULTI) returns another interface belonging to that package. What would I do in this scenario? Implementing that interface myself seems out of the question.

Similarly, as usage of this client grows, my own implementation can grow to the point that it implements the whole interface to Redis - this seems to go against the whole idea of delegating this out to an external dependency.

Is there a better way to test third-party packages like this, for things such as error handling?

Comment: Why does it seem out of the question to you? I think it's perfectly fine to declare a new interface that is implemented by `redis.Pipeline` and have your `RedisClient.TxPipeline` method return that interface instead of `redis.Pipeline`.

Comment: What conclusion did you ultimately come to? I have a similar dilemma.

Comment: @Lansana My approach is essentially as below, with integration tests covering interactions with any dependencies. For something non-specific to Redis, or anything that can't be tested with an integration test as such, mkopriva's suggestion also works.

Comment: Care to share a dummy example of your Redis implementation?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

One approach would be to create a type that focuses on what you want to accomplish instead on what methods of the client you are using.

Let's say all you want is a storage to save and fetch users, you could imagine an interface like this:

```
type UserStore interface {
  SaveUser(*User) error
  GetUserByID(id string) (*User, error)
  SearchUsers(query string) ([]User, error)
}
```

You could then implement a Redis version of this storage and call whatever client methods you want inside, it doesn't matter. You can even implement one in PostgreSQL or whatever.
Also, mocking is way easier with this approach since you all you need to do is to implement this interface instead of the Redis one.

Here is an example of a mock version of this interface:

```
type UserStoreMock struct {
  SaveUserFn func (*User) error
  SaveUserInvoked bool
  ...
}

func (m *UserStoreMock) SaveUser(u *User) error {
  m.SaveUserInvoked = true

  if m.SaveUserFn != nil {
    return m.SaveUserFn(u)
  }

  return nil
}
...
```

You can then use this mock in tests like this:

```
var m UserStoreMock

m.SaveUserFn = func(u *User) error {
  if u.ID != "123" {
    t.Fail("Bad ID")
  }

  return ErrDuplicateError
}
...
```

Comment: The implementation of `UserStore` and how it interacts with redis is ultimately what I'm trying to test - for example, I want to assert that if an error is returned by redis, then this error is handled correctly. This is why I'm trying to mock out the redis client.

Comment: Testing each implementation of `UserStore` requires using no mocks IMO but making actual calls because even if you are mocking you can't be sure that your implementation will work the same way without mock (imagine how hard it would be with PostgreSQL). This approach gives you the flexibility to isolate the actual Redis tests from the rest of your code which would be able to only work with a mock `UserStore`.

Comment: @cejast Asdine's code example is definitely the way you're gonna want to go, as it's a clean design. You can still follow his recommendation for using mocks, etc. for testing. If you want to test how YOUR code interacts with an error from the Redis client, simply return an error from your mock client. If you want to test that your code will actually work with a real instance of Redis, you will have to write an integration test or two.